# "Encoding 1252 data could not be found" iTextSharp use Japanese font

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

I use Unity2018.2.3f1 and iTextSharp.
Although basic PDF creation was possible, Japanese fonts can not be used on Windows.
The following source code works correctly on Mac.

```
try {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader ( basePath );
    Document document = new Document ( reader.GetPageSize ( 1 ) );

    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream ( newPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write );
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance ( document, fileStream );
    document.Open ();

    PdfContentByte pdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent;
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage ( reader, 1 );
    pdfContentByte.AddTemplate ( page, 0, 0 );

    string fontName = Path.Combine ( Application.streamingAssetsPath, "mplus-1c-medium.ttf" );
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont ( fontName, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED );
    pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize ( bf, 10.0f );

    pdfContentByte.BeginText ();
    pdfContentByte.ShowText ( new PdfTextArray ( "文字列" ) );
    pdfContentByte.SetFontAndSize ( bf, 20.0f );
    pdfContentByte.MoveText ( 50, 50 );
    pdfContentByte.ShowText ( new PdfTextArray ( "文字列1" ) );
    pdfContentByte.ShowText ( new PdfTextArray ( "2" ) );
    pdfContentByte.EndText ();

    document.Close ();
    fileStream.Close ();
    writer.Close ();
    reader.Close ();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    handyAlert.text = "Error1:"+ex.Message;
    Debug.Log ( ex.StackTrace);
}
```

However, the following error occurs on Windows.

> Encoding 1252 data could not be found. Make sure you have correct
>   international codeset assembly installed and enabled.

The font used is as follows. Since it operates normally on the Mac, I think that there is no problem with the font file itself.
https://mplus-fonts.osdn.jp

In addition, if part of BaseFont.CreateFont is made as follows, the part of numbers other than Japanese is written normally.

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont ( BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED );
```

Please tell me how to solve.

Comment: It may need Windows-1252 for Times Roman.  If you don't have it, there's a package for it on nuget. https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages/

Comment: Thank you for comment. I imported System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, but the result did not change. As I wrote in the question, no error will occur when TIMES_ROMAN is used, characters are written in the PDF with the Japanese part disappearing like "1", "2".

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. I need "I18N.dll" and "I18N.West.dll".
After installing these two dlls in the Plugins folder of Unity project and building the application it worked just fine.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/42955/codepage-1252-not-supported-works-in-editor-but-no.html